# showing data in console but not inside modal in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Particular user Details

```
invoice_info: [],



this.$http.get(`/api/invoice-generator-retrieve/${nid}/`)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.invoice_info = res.data.data;
                        console.log(res.data.data, "State", this.invoice_info.invoice_generator_id)
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
```

Storing below data in the invoice_info[],

```
invoice_generator_id:5
is_paid:false
total_amount:7000
total_tk:7150
updated_at:"2023-01-25T16:17:15.187859"
user_id:4656
```

```
<h5 class="modal-title font22think ml-4" id="exampleModalLabel" >${
                        this.invoice_info.user_id }</h5>
```

**On Modal ${ this.invoice_info.user_id } is showing instead the result should be 4656**

any idead to fix this issue?

Comment: In vue use `{{  }}` to display value in template

Comment: I have tried with {{ }} also but nothing shows at DOM.

Comment: Try `{{ invoice_info.user_id }}`

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: in vue devtools the data in the Array of invoice_info is not appearing. The data appears after reload. Whereas console is showing data from the exact same array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since my above code failed to work accordingly I managed them to work by getting the element by Id and inject the value.

Comment: This is not a good solution; you've bypassed Vue's state management by manipulating the DOM directly. This *will* cause confusing and difficult-to-solve bugs in the future, when Vue rerenders those components with what it thinks is the current state, overwriting your injected values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel but I absolute failed to work my code with state. And surprisingly other sates are working absolutely fine except this one that's why I had to go with this solution.

Comment: OK, just be aware that this solution is guaranteed to fail in difficult-to-debug ways once you start adding in other components that might trigger these rerendering. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again Daniel. I will surely keep that on mind. Have a nice day mate!

Comment: This is not an answer to original problem statement. Instead you could edit your post and add this as temporary/hacky fix and you never know someone out there can figure out the right solution